# No sound on Virtualbox with Mac OS Mojave as guest

Tags: sound, virtualbox, macosx

Hi I installed MacOS Mojave in virtualbox, everything is working fine except sound, there are no input and output devices showing in MACOS guest.

[image]

[image]

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 and using latest virtualbox 6.0.1

I would also like to mention that its working super fine in wmware, But I don't wanna use that as there are some graphics issues.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still tracking down audio but the above answer on screen resolution is just not correct. Run this from your Virtual Box install location. I've ran this on Windows 10 and have full screen.

`VBoxManage setextradata "<your VM Name>" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1920x1080`

Note: Be sure to change `<your VM Name>` to the name of your VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I did not need the audio input for my virtual box instance so I unchecked the "Enable Audio Input" option from sound settings of Virtual box and got my host's sound back.